# Highchart shows only 12 categories

Tags: php, jquery, graph

Hi guys I'm having a trouble working with Highchart. I think my error is when the category is more than 12. here's my code:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['ARC', 'CLM', 'COLREP', 'CUI', 'FB', 'IOH', 'IST', 'LCV', 'LCWSLC', 'LOGDFR', 'LOGDRT', 'LOGGLE', 
                        'LOGGT', 'LOGSR', 'LOGVL', 'LST', 'OARD', 'OARP', 'OARPPP', 'POR', 'PRIN', 'SLRD', 'SLRS', 'SLRSUP', 'SVTCBR', 
                        'SVTSP', 'SVTST', 'TKD', 'TR', 'USO']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [400.6, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 100.9]
        }]
    });
});
```

});​

I already try to put the categories in array variable but same result show.

x-axis only show 12 categories. the example on there site is good for 12 categories. Is anyone know how to fix this problem or configure anything in the plugin?

here's there demo page http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

thanks in advance!

Comment: data array length must equals to categories array length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have series with only 12 Values within each array ,so if there's only 12 Values it will pick up first 12 Categories .

High chart's wont show Categories without data related to them using Series ,just put 18 next 0 Values at Series Array and it will show those Categories .

Comment: Yeah that's my error. Thanks guys especially to you cody. this problem  solved.